# Валидация xml файла по xsd

Tags: c++, xml

Недавно познакомился с xsd схемами, которые я начал использовать для проверки xml файлов перед парсингом, что существенно облегчило работу. Проблема в том, что для валидации я использую `Qt` который для этого имеет необходимые классы (`QXmlValidator` и `QXmlSchema`), но если валидация нужна за пределами `Qt` приложения? Есть что-нибудь легковесное для этих целей?

Comment: На Unix есть libxml2, на счёт компиляции на остальные платформы я не знаю.

Comment: libxml2 даже более кроссплатформенный чем Qt.